# Google spreadsheet: Imported XML content cannot be parsed

Tags: xml, import, google-sheets, parse-error

Trying to scrape a soccer results site for my spreadsheet I use:

> =IMPORTXML("http://www.flashscore.com/match/Ov7BcLEp","//*[@id='flashscore']/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/span[1]/text()")

This works perfectly fine from within the google console in Chrome:

> $x("//*[@id='flashscore']/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/span[1]/text()")

However, it fails when I paste the above into a cell on a google spreadsheet.

Any ideas are appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug on the new spreadsheet. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22031389/457557
Try it on an old google spreadsheet and it should work !