# How can I import Website Data into Google Sheets?

Tags: import, google-sheets

I have no idea how to import the data from [this](https://www.oanda.com/lang/de/forex-trading/analysis/open-position-ratios) into my google spreadsheet.

I tryed the following which did not work:

```
=importxml(A1,"//div[@class='instrument style-scope position-ratios-app'")
```

"A1" refers to the link on the top.

Can anyone help me? 
Thx

Comment: There is a real problem with scraping data from this site. The data is loaded dynamically after the page is loaded. The loading is also quite complex with each currency pair coming from a different site. Furthermore there is security blocking access. Although this reply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383502/google-spreadsheet-getting-text-with-importxml shows some good techniques, my guess is that you will need to use more sophisticated tools to get this data (maybe curl in a node.js program)

Answer (score 0):

in the meanwhile I have found an API for this website but I have no idea how to use this in gsheet:

curl \
  –compressed \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer " \
  "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/instruments/USD_JPY/positionBook"

Any idea?