# Is there a way to import results from this name generator?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

As a game designer and writer, I use fantasynamegenerators.com a lot. I'd like to find a way to import results from these name generators into Google Sheets. I've had some success with other sites, but I'm having no luck here.

This is as far as I've gotten:

1. Use developer tools to inspect <https://www.fantasynamegenerators.com/username-generator.php>
2. Copy XPath for desired content `//*[@id='result']`
3. Enter formula in Google Sheets `IMPORTXML(https://www.fantasynamegenerators.com/username-generator.php,"//*[@id='result']/text()")`
4. I got an "Imported content is empty" error, so I tried a couple XPath variations, including `//*[@id='result']/text()`

None of that did the trick, still getting the same error.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217955/importxml-imported-content-empty), I'm guessing that I'm encountering the same issue ("the content is loaded using jQuery") but I can't confirm this because I know nothing about jQuery. I also have no idea how to track down the URL for the jQuery content, as suggested.

Any help is appreciated! If I can find a solution it'll open up a lot of options for my workflow.

Comment: You're overcomplicating this. If you check the source you can see the name generator is in a file named `usernames.js` it contains an array of all 670 available names and some JS code to randomly pick some from it when the button is clicked. All you need to do is copy that array.

Comment: I was dubious about plagiarism here, but given that the notice at the bottom of the site states `You're free to use names on this site to name anything in any of your own works`, here's the link to the file I mentioned: https://www.fantasynamegenerators.com/scripts/usernames.js

Comment: It appears I was! Thank you for your help! Out of curiosity, what exactly are you doing when you "check the source"? Chrome developer tools are still kind of overwhelming for me as an amateur coder.

Comment: Yeah it can be :) To find it I inspected the generate button in the DOM, checked what click event handlers it had and found the function it called, then searched for that in the 'sources' tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste this formula anywhere you wish:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({RANDBETWEEN(ROW(A1:A1661), 999^99),
 {"Pixelephant";"Ninjavu";"Pignorant";"Plazy";"Pandaily";"Tweetail";"Coillness";"Evillan";"Lazyhazy";"Sniperil";"Accentaur";"Aggrobot";"Alfairy";"Alpaking";"Alphairy";"Alphantom";"Amighost";"Amigod";"Amigoliath";"Annaconda";"Antelopez";"Antiger";"Apeshifter";"Apexecutioner";"Aquasp";"ArchLizard";"Armydillo";"Aromaster";"Asprince";"Asprincess";"Autoad";"Babeast";"Baboom";"Babuccaneer";"Bachelord";"Baconjurer";"Baconqueror";"Badept";"Badgericho";"Bambinosaur";"Bambooccaneer";"Bamboozle";"Banditch";"Banditto";"Bandroid";"Bansheep";"Barnaclue";"Baroqueen";"Barracupid";"Barrycuda";"Basalamander";"Bassassin";"Basshopper";"BearCrawl";"BearGills";"Bearry";"BeastLee";"Beastern";"Beauty-Rex";"Beezenees";"Behemote";"Binghost";"Bingoblin";"Bingod";"Bingoddess";"Bingoliath";"Blazebra";"Bluffalo";"Boaris";"Bombeast";"Bonghost";"Bongoliath";"Bonsiren";"Boohooligan";"Brassassin";"Brasshopper";"Broncoco";"Brutea";"Brutee-Rex";"BuffaLou";"Buffaloris";"Bullfrogert";"BumbleBeast";"BumbleBeetle";"BumblingBee";"BunBunny";"Butcherry";"Butterflight";"Butterflux";"C-Horse";"C-Lion";"Calamarauder";"Camella";"Camperor";"Candroid";"Capeshifter";"Caribooboo";"Cariboohoo";"Caterpixie";"Caterpolaris";"Catnip";"Celestiger";"Centaura";"Centaurora";"Champeon";"Cheatah";"Chieftaint";"Chimpanther";"Chimpantzer";"Chimpanzer";"Chimpanzy";"Chinchillax";"Chinchilling";"Chipmunkey";"Chosenpai";"Cicadaemon";"Cinnamonster";"Civillain";"Classhopper";"Cloverlord";"Cloverseer";"Coalossus";"Cobrag";"Cobrass";"Cobrawl";"Cocowboy";"Cocowgirl";"Colossubs";"Commandrogenic";"Commandroid";"Conjursa";"Conquerogue";"Conquerry";"Consoldier";"Consoul";"Controll";"Corsairier";"Corsairway";"Cougarfield";"Cougarry";"Cowhale";"Coyotea";"Coyoteerex";"Creaturret";"Crickettle";"Criminail";"Critturtle";"Croccultist";"Crocodino";"Crocodoom";"Crocodoris";"Cubeast";"Cyaninja";"Cybora";"Cybork";"Cyborne";"Cycloth";"Daemonk";"Daemonkey";"Daemonster";"Decorsair";"Delhiminate";"Demonkey";"Demonster";"Devile";"Devillain";"Dimwitch";"Dingoal";"Dingopher";"Dinomite";"Dinosause";"Dinoscythe";"Dinosoaring";"Dismage";"Dismaiden";"Dismister";"Diwrecktor";"Dolphine";"Dolphinkle";"Domignome";"DonKiwi";"Donkeychain";"Draccoon";"Dragonflight";"Dragonightmare";"Drummingbird";"Duelf";"Duskunk";"Dwarvo";"Dwarvos";"Eggcecutioner";"Elephantom";"Eliminature";"Eliminatured";"Emoo";"Emperoar";"Emprescue";"Emufasa";"Emufassa";"Emutant";"Enchantra";"Essaint";"Eurobot";"ExTermite";"Executie";"Eyewearwolf";"Falconartist";"Falcondor";"Falconjure";"Falconjurer";"Fearkat";"Fellama";"Festivalkyrie";"Fiendure";"Flaminghost";"Flamingoal";"Flamingoat";"Flamingopher";"Flexecutioner";"Fowlee";"Frenchanter";"Froghurt";"Frostrich";"Fuguru";"Gamercenary";"Gamermaid";"Gamerman";"Gangstereo";"Gangsteroids";"Geckoco";"Geishadow";"Gerbilbo";"Ghostrich";"GiantPandaisy";"GiantPandame";"GiantPandamonium";"Giantics";"Gibbonbon";"Gigangster";"Giraffiki";"Giraffle";"Gladiablo";"Glamorc";"Glasshopper";"Globster";"Gnunou";"Goath";"Gobling";"Goghost";"Goliatlas";"Gooze";"Gopherrel";"Gorillala";"Gorillamp";"Gorillax";"Gorrilag";"Gorrilava";"Grammarauder";"Grampaladin";"Grapeshifter";"Grasshiphopper";"Griffinish";"Griffinished";"Griffinite";"Griffinkle";"Griminal";"Grincubus";"Gringoblin";"Gringoliath";"GuacaMole";"GuineaPiggy";"GuineaPiglet";"Guruse";"Hamsteroids";"Harlequill";"Havoccultist";"Hawkeye";"Hawkward";"Hedgehawk";"Hedgehoax";"Hedgehog";"Hedgehogger";"Herobot";"Herogue";"Herose";"Herover";"Herringmaster";"Hexecutioner";"Hijackal";"Hippolice";"Hippony";"Hippopotamouse";"Hitmanatee";"Hitmantis";"Hobogre";"HoneyBeetle";"HoneyBeezenees";"Hornettle";"Hoverlord";"Hydroid";"Hydrone";"Hyenada";"Hyenanana";"Hypnotastic";"Hypnotwist";"Hypogre";"Ibiscuit";"Ibiscus";"Iconjurer";"Impaladin";"Incubugs";"Incubuzz";"Indighost";"Indigoliath";"Infergnome";"Jackalf";"Jaguardo";"Jaguwar";"Jalapegnome";"Javampire";"Jellyfists";"Jollygator";"Judgenie";"Judgerm";"Kangaroar";"Kangaroodle";"Kangarookie";"Kappaladin";"Karmagician";"Kegnome";"Kimognome";"Knightclub";"Knighthawk";"Knightingale";"Knightlife";"Knightmare";"Knightshade";"Knighttime";"Koalala";"Koalarry";"Koalassy";"Koalava";"KomodoreDragon";"Komodough";"Komodozer";"Lamagician";"Lamaster";"Laserpent";"Lassassin";"Latignome";"Lavampire";"Lemonster";"Lemurmur";"Leopardon";"Leoparty";"Leprecocoa";"Leprecorn";"Leviatank";"Liquidathor";"Liquidatorus";"Llamaths";"Lobsteroid";"Lobsteroids";"Lockroach";"Locustard";"Loghost";"Macaward";"Madept";"Magmaster";"Magpiechart";"MammothMoth";"Manateerex";"Manghost";"Mantissue";"Marauderby";"Masteroid";"MatriarchAngel";"MatriarchMage";"Mavericksha";"Maybeast";"Meerkatnip";"Megangster";"Metrobot";"Minerd";"Misteroid";"Mobsteroid";"Mobsteroids";"Mockroach";"Monkeyno";"Monkiwi";"Mosquiche";"Mosquitar";"Mosquite";"Mosquitoxic";"Muskunk";"Mutantra";"Napaladin";"Ninja";"Ninjafar";"Ninjava";"Nitrobot";"Nitrogue";"Nitrover";"Nitwitch";"Numbat";"Ocelotus";"Octopirate";"Octopixy";"Octopuds";"Octopuppy";"Ogremlin";"Omegangster";"Omenforcer";"Orangutangle";"Orangutango";"Orangutank";"Orangutitan";"Origamister";"Ostricheyrich";"Ostritches";"Otterminate";"Otterror";"Ownerd";"OysterSauce";"Oysterminate";"Oystrich";"Paladino";"Pandaisy";"Pandame";"Pandamonium";"Pandata";"Panthermal";"Panthermic";"Paparazzombie";"Parascythe";"Parasike";"Parasyclops";"Parrotting";"PatriachAngel";"PatriarchMage";"Patrio";"Patriode";"Patroll";"Peafowlet";"Pedroid";"Pelgriminal";"Pelgrimp";"Pelicancan";"Pelicandy";"Pelicanine";"Pelicannon";"Penguinee";"Phantomahawk";"Phantomato";"Phantomb";"Phantomboy";"Phantomcat";"Phantomfool";"Pheasantics";"Phoenexus";"Phoenixia";"Piagnome";"Pigloo";"Pignite";"Pillagerman";"Pionearly";"Pitapatriot";"Pixelf";"Pixigh";"Poltergeisha";"Ponylon";"Ponymph";"Porcupid";"Porcupie";"Porcupike";"Porcupint";"Porcupity";"Porcupixel";"Porpoison";"Potatoad";"Preaster";"Prepatriarch";"Priestar";"Priestyle";"Proccultist";"Proctopus";"Pupillager";"Pygmeanie";"Pyrobot";"Pyrogre";"Pyrogue";"Quailment";"Rabbite";"Rabbyte";"Rangerman";"Raptortilla";"Raptortoise";"Rascalf";"Rebelf";"Reconjurer";"Recyclops";"RedHerring";"RedPandaisy";"RedPandame";"Rerunner";"Rerunt";"Retrobot";"Retrogue";"Revenano";"Rhignome";"Rhinocerious";"Rhinosaur";"Rivalkyrie";"Robottom";"Roguerrilla";"Roverlord";"Roverseer";"Sailorc";"Sailord";"Sailore";"Sailoreal";"Saladiator";"Salamaniac";"Salamantis";"Salmonkey";"Salmonster";"Samuraider";"Sardiner";"Sasquire";"Sassassin";"Scampirate";"Scarabyte";"Scentaur";"Scorpeon";"Scraptor";"SeaLionness";"Sealectric";"Sealite";"Sealixir";"Sellamander";"Sewarlock";"Irrelephant";"Sha-Doh";"Shadept";"Sharcade";"Sharctic";"Sheeple";"Sincubus";"Sirenforcer";"Sirental";"Sitcommander";"Slayerk";"Slother";"Slotherworld";"Slotherworldly";"SnailMail";"Snailment";"Snakebab";"Sniperipheral";"Sniperks";"Sniperv";"Snowmanta";"Snowmantis";"Sockroach";"Soyster";"Spaladin";"Sparasite";"Sparrowling";"Specterminate";"Spiderby";"Spillager";"Spookworm";"Spreest";"Spright";"Squidiot";"Squidle";"Squidol";"Starfishht";"Starfissure";"Starfist";"Stenchanter";"StingRaymond";"Stingraider";"StingrayCharles";"Stinkbuggy";"Stoutlaw";"Succubusted";"Sukiyaking";"Sultank";"Sultantrum";"Sumogre";"Sundaemon";"Sunraider";"SwallowRider";"Tabooccaneer";"Tabutcher";"Tangoddess";"Techgnome";"Teriyaking";"Termight";"Termime";"Termitis";"Thortoise";"Titank";"Tomatoad";"Totemperor";"Totemplar";"Toucancan";"Toucandy";"Toucane";"Toucannon";"Toucanoe";"Tourtoise";"Trollout";"Troutlaw";"Troutwards";"Tsardine";"Turbandit";"Turbanshee";"Turbogre";"Turkiwi";"Twilightingale";"Typogre";"Unbandit";"Unbanshee";"Uniqueen";"Urchinchilla";"Valord";"Vanillama";"Vertighost";"Victorc";"Videogre";"Vikingkong";"Vikingpin";"Vipersia";"Volcagnome";"Vulturret";"Wahooligan";"Wallaby";"Walruse";"Warachnid";"Warhawk";"Warlocket";"Warthawk";"Waspear";"Weaselfie";"Wenchanter";"Wincubus";"Windighost";"Witchy";"Wizart";"Wolferal";"Wolfire";"Wolveriot";"Wolverival";"Wombait";"Wombattalion";"Wombattle";"Womblast";"Woodpecan";"Woodpecs";"Wrathhawk";"Wrathhog";"Yahooligan";"Yakar";"Yetea";"Zebrag";"Zebrass";"Zebrawl";"ZerobotPixelephant";"Zerobot";"Acrobatic";"Acting";"Action";"Active";"Adorable";"Advice";"Advise";"Afternoon";"Agile";"Air";"Alien";"Amazing";"Amused";"Amusing";"Ancient";"Angel";"Angelic";"Anger";"Angry";"Antique";"Aqua";"Arch";"Arctic";"Artistic";"Ash";"Asking";"Attack";"Attractive";"Aunt";"Authority";"Autumn";"Awesome";"Awful";"Awkward";"Baby";"Bad";"Baking";"Balance";"Balloon";"Bath";"Battle";"Beautiful";"Bed";"Big";"BigBad";"Bitter";"Black";"Blade";"Bland";"Blind";"Blood";"Blue";"Blushing";"Bold";"Bony";"Bouncing";"Bouncy";"Box";"Brave";"Breakfast";"Bright";"Broken";"Bronze";"Brother";"Brown";"Bruised";"Brutish";"Bubble";"Bubbly";"Calm";"Candid";"Candy";"Cannon";"Careful";"Careless";"Caring";"Chain";"Change";"Charge";"Charming";"Cheap";"Cheat";"Cheating";"Cheerful";"Cheery";"Chief";"Chill";"Chilly";"Classic";"Clean";"Clever";"Club";"Clueless";"Clumsy";"Coach";"Cold";"Color";"Colorful";"Complex";"Computer";"Confused";"Consult";"Control";"Cooking";"Cool";"Copper";"Corny";"Corrupt";"Country";"Covert";"Crafty";"Crash";"Crazy";"Creative";"Creepy";"Criminal";"Crooked";"Crown";"Cruel";"Cuddly";"Curly";"Cute";"Dance";"Dancing";"Dapper";"Dark";"Darling";"Daughter";"Daydream";"Dazzling";"Dead";"Death";"Defiant";"Delirious";"Desert";"Design";"Diet";"Digital";"Dim";"Dinner";"Dirty";"Discrete";"Dizzy";"Doctor";"Doom";"Dopey";"Dream";"Droopy";"Dust";"Eager";"Ecstatic";"Elder";"Electric";"Elegant";"Embarrased";"Emotional";"Enchanted";"Enchanting";"Enormous";"Enraged";"Euphoric";"Evening";"Evil";"Excited";"Exotic";"Expert";"Fabulous";"Fact";"Fake";"FALSE";"Family";"Famous";"Fancy";"Fantastic";"Farm";"Fast";"Fat";"Father";"Fearless";"Feisty";"Fickle";"Fiery";"Filthy";"Fire";"First";"Flamboyant";"Flame";"Flashy";"Flawless";"Flimsy";"Fluffy";"Foolish";"Force";"Forest";"Formal";"Forsaken";"Free";"Fresh";"Friendly";"Frightened";"Frightening";"Frizzy";"Frosty";"Frozen";"Fruit";"Funny";"Fur";"Furry";"Fuzzy";"Game";"Gamer";"Gaming";"Garden";"Gentle";"Ghost";"Giant";"Gifted";"Glamorous";"Glass";"Glittering";"Gloomy";"Glorious";"Golden";"Good";"Gorgeous";"Gothic";"Graceful";"Gracious";"Grand";"Grass";"Grave";"Gray";"Great";"Greedy";"Green";"Grim";"Grizzly";"Ground";"Grumpy";"Gummy";"Hairy";"Hammer";"Handsome";"Happy";"Harmless";"Harsh";"Haunted";"Haunting";"Healthy";"Heart";"Heavy";"Helpful";"Hidden";"Hilarious";"History";"Hollow";"Home";"Honest";"Honor";"Hope";"Horrible";"Huge";"Hugging";"Humble";"Humor";"Hungry";"Icky";"Icy";"Identical";"Idiotic";"Idle";"Illegal";"Imaginary";"Impossible";"Impulse";"Incredible";"Infamous";"Infernal";"Innocent";"Insecure";"Intelligent";"Iron";"Island";"Jealous";"Jelly";"Joke";"Jolly";"Journey";"Jumbo";"Jungle";"Junior";"Keyboard";"Kind";"Kissy";"Knowledge";"Lake";"Land";"Laser";"Laughing";"Lazy";"Light";"Lightning";"Liquid";"Little";"Lone";"Lonely";"Lost";"Loud";"Lovable";"Love";"Loyal";"Lucky";"Lunch";"Mad";"Magic";"Magical";"Magma";"Majestic";"Marble";"Marsh";"Masked";"Mean";"Mega";"Mellow";"Memory";"Merry";"Messy";"Midnight";"Mild";"Mimic";"Mini";"Money";"Morning";"Mother";"Mountain";"Mud";"Mushy";"Music";"Musical";"Mysterious";"Mystery";"Naive";"Naughty";"Needy";"Nervous";"Night";"Nightmare";"Nimble";"Nutty";"Obvious";"Ocean";"Odd";"Old";"Opinion";"Orange";"Ordinary";"Original";"Pale";"Paper";"Parallel";"Party";"Peace";"Peaceful";"Perfect";"Perfumed";"Perky";"Pesky";"Phantom";"Phony";"Pink";"Plastic";"Play";"Playful";"Plush";"Poison";"Polite";"Poor";"Posh";"Positive";"Pretty";"Prime";"Prison";"Proud";"Puny";"Pure";"Quick";"Quiet";"Quirky";"Radioactive";"Rain";"Rapid";"Rare";"Reckless";"Record";"Recording";"Red";"Respect";"Rhythm";"Rich";"Riddle";"River";"Road";"Rock";"Room";"Rotten";"Royal";"Rude";"Rusty";"Sad";"Sand";"Scared";"Scary";"Scented";"School";"Science";"Sea";"Secret";"Selfish";"Serene";"Shadow";"Shady";"Shallow";"Shiny";"Short";"Show";"Shy";"Silent";"Silk";"Silly";"Silver";"Simple";"Sister";"Sleep";"Sleeping";"Sleepy";"Slow";"Small";"Smart";"Smiling";"Smooth";"Smug";"Sneaky";"Snow";"Soft";"Son";"Song";"Sour";"Spooky";"Spotless";"Spotted";"Spring";"Stark";"Steam";"Steel";"Storm";"Strange";"Strong";"Stylish";"Subtle";"Sugar";"Summer";"Surprise";"Swamp";"Swift";"Tall";"Terrific";"Throne";"Thunder";"Time";"Tiny";"Tired";"Trained";"Travel";"Troubled";"Trusty";"Twin";"Ugly";"Uncle";"Unique";"Unusual";"Upset";"Vague";"Vain";"Venom";"Vicious";"Violent";"Violet";"Virtual";"Volcano";"Voyage";"War";"Water";"Wax";"Weird";"White";"Wiggly";"Wild";"Wind";"Winter";"Wise";"Witty";"Worthy";"Writer";"Writing";"Wrong";"Yellow";"Young";"Albatross";"Alligator";"Almond";"Alpaca";"Android";"Ant";"Antelope";"Ape";"Apple";"Apricot";"Armadillo";"Arrow";"Assassin";"Avocado";"Baboon";"Badger";"Ball";"Banana";"Bandit";"Banshee";"Barracuda";"Bat";"Bear";"Beaver";"Bee";"Beetle";"Berry";"Birdie";"Bison";"Blackberry";"Blizzard";"BloodElf";"Blossom";"Blueberry";"Boar";"Boomer";"Bot";"Boulder";"Boy";"Bronco";"Brownie";"Bruiser";"Buffalo";"Bug";"Bull";"Bullet";"Bullfrog";"Buster";"Butterfly";"Cake";"Calf";"Camel";"Captain";"Caribou";"Cat";"Caterpillar";"Centaur";"Champ";"Champion";"Charger";"Cheetah";"Cherry";"Chick";"Chicken";"Chimera";"Chimp";"Chimpanzee";"Chomper";"Clam";"Cobra";"Coconut";"Cod";"Coffee";"Colonel";"Colt";"Conqueror";"Cookie";"Cow";"Coyote";"Cranberry";"Crane";"Crocodile";"Crow";"Cruncher";"Crusader";"Cub";"Custard";"Cyborg";"Cyclops";"Daemon";"Deer";"Defender";"Demon";"Dessert";"Devil";"Dino";"Dinosaur";"Diva";"Dog";"Doggy";"Dolphin";"Donkey";"Dots";"Doughnut";"Dove";"Dragon";"Dragonfly";"Drake";"Droid";"Drummer";"Duck";"Duckling";"Duke";"Dunker";"Dutchess";"Dwarf";"Eagle";"Eel";"Eland";"Elephant";"Elf";"Emu";"Enigma";"Fairy";"Falcon";"Fawn";"Fay";"Ferret";"Fiend";"Fig";"Figure";"Fish";"Fishy";"Flamingo";"Flash";"Fledgling";"Flower";"Fly";"Foal";"Fortune";"Fowl";"Fox";"Frog";"Frogger";"Froglet";"Fry";"Fury";"Gangster";"General";"Genie";"Gerbil";"Giraffe";"Girl";"Gnoll";"Gnu";"Goat";"Goblin";"God";"Goddess";"Goldfish";"Goliath";"Goose";"Grape";"Grapefruit";"Grasshopper";"Griffin";"Grin";"Guardian";"GuineaPig";"Gull";"Guy";"Halfling";"Hamster";"Hare";"Harpy";"Hatchling";"Haunt";"Hawk";"Hazelnut";"Hero";"Heroine";"Herring";"Hippo";"Hobbit";"Hoglet";"Hooper";"Hopper";"Horse";"Hound";"Hummingbird";"Hunter";"Hurricane";"Hydra";"Hyena";"Ibis";"Idol";"Immortal";"Imp";"Incubus";"Infant";"Jackal";"Jaguar";"Jellyfish";"Judge";"Juniper";"Juvenile";"Kangaroo";"Khajiit";"King";"Kingfisher";"Kit";"Kitten";"Kitty";"Kiwi";"Knight";"Koala";"KomodoDragon";"Kraken";"Lady";"Lamb";"Lark";"Larva";"Leaf";"Leech";"Lemon";"Lemur";"Leopard";"Leprechaun";"Lice";"Lime";"Lion";"Lizard";"Llama";"Lobster";"Locust";"Lord";"Lynx";"Macaw";"Machine";"Mage";"Maggot";"Magician";"Magpie";"Maiden";"Mallard";"Mammoth";"Manatee";"Mandarin";"Mango";"Mantis";"Maple";"Maverick";"Meerkat";"Melon";"Mermaid";"Merman";"Minotaur";"Mite";"Mobster";"Mole";"Mongoose";"Monk";"Monkey";"Monster";"Moose";"Mosquito";"Mouse";"Mule";"Muppet";"Mutant";"Necromancer";"Nestling";"Newt";"NightElf";"Nightingale";"Nova";"Nugget";"Nut";"Nymph";"Oak";"Ocelot";"Octopus";"Ogre";"Okapi";"Olive";"Oracle";"Orangutan";"Orc";"Ostrich";"Otter";"Owl";"Owlet";"Ox";"Oyster";"Paladin";"Palm";"Panda";"Panther";"Papaya";"Parrot";"Patriot";"Pattern";"Peafowl";"Peanut";"Pear";"Pecan";"Pegasus";"Pelican";"Penguin";"Pepper";"Petal";"Phantasm";"Pheasant";"Phoenix";"Pie";"Pig";"Pigeon";"Piggy";"Piglet";"Pineapple";"Pirate";"Pixie";"Plum";"Pony";"Porcupine";"Porpoise";"Potato";"Predator";"Priest";"Priestess";"Prince";"Princess";"Prophet";"Prowler";"Pug";"Puggle";"Pumpkin";"Pup";"Puppy";"Pygmy";"Python";"Quail";"Queen";"Rabbit";"Raccoon";"Raider";"Ram";"Ranger";"Raptor";"Rascal";"Raspberry";"Rat";"RedPanda";"Reindeer";"Revenant";"Rhino";"Rhinoceros";"Roach";"Robot";"Rogue";"Rose";"Rover";"Runner";"Sage";"Sailor";"Saint";"Salamander";"Salmon";"Sardine";"Satyr";"Scorpion";"SeaLion";"SeaUrchin";"Seahorse";"Seal";"Seer";"Serpent";"Shade";"Shark";"Sheep";"Shifter";"Siren";"Skeleton";"Skunk";"Slider";"Slingshot";"Sloth";"Smile";"Smirk";"Snail";"Snake";"Snowman";"Soldier";"Soul";"Sparkle";"Sparks";"Sparrow";"Specter";"Sphinx";"Spider";"Spike";"Spirit";"Spook";"Sprite";"Squab";"Squid";"Squire";"Squirrel";"Stalker";"Starfish";"Stingray";"Stinkbug";"Stitches";"Stomper";"Stork";"Strawbery";"Stripes";"Succubus";"Sunflower";"Swallow";"Swan";"T-Rex";"Tadpole";"Tauren";"Tea";"Techy";"Termite";"Terror";"Thief";"Tiger";"Titan";"Toad";"Toffee";"Tomato";"Tortoise";"Toucan";"Troll";"Trooper";"Trout";"Tucan";"Tulip";"Tumbler";"Turkey";"Turtle";"Twinkle";"Twinkles";"Unicorn";"Urchin";"Valkyrie";"Vampire";"Vanilla";"Viking";"Villain";"Viper";"Void";"Vulture";"Walker";"Walrus";"Warhog";"Warlock";"Warrior";"Warthog";"Wasp";"Watermelon";"Weasel";"Werewolf";"Whale";"Whelp";"Willow";"Witch";"Wizard";"Wolf";"Wolverine";"Wombat";"Woodpecker";"Worm";"Wraith";"Wrecker";"Yak";"Yeti";"Yew";"Zebra";"Zombie"}}, 
 "select Col2 order by Col1 limit 10", 0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rory who pointed out that I was doing things the hard way!

> The solution is to track down the original file containing the source array.

1. Open developer tools and go to the Source tab.
2. Go to (site URL) > Scripts > .js file
3. Copy to .txt file, remove extraneous JavaScript.
4. Import to Google Sheets.

Thanks again!