# "Imported Content Is Empty"

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to link a specific number from a site using the Xpath but it keeps saying the content is empty.

This is the xpath:

```
//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]
```

Using formula: `importxml`

This is what I have input into Google Sheets:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://scaletec.locateinv.com/app#/inventory/part/3031/inventory","/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th[7]")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importxml Imported Content Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217955/importxml-imported-content-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets does not support scraping of data behind login page, nor JavaScript content therefore this is not possible.