# IMPORTXML giving "Imported Content is Empty error"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import some text from the internet but apparently google sheets doesn't handle dinamic websites. I used the Xpath from Chrome browser.

These were the solutions that I was working on but none of them worked.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.kite.com/python/docs/pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.sum","//*[@id='root']/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/section/div/code/text()") 

=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.kite.com/python/docs/pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.sum","//*[@id='root']/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/section/div/code/text()"),1;1)
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can I ask you about the values you want to retrieve?

Comment: I want to retrieve the documentation about the function.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw the HTML of the URL, it seems that the document you want is shown using Javascript. In this case, the values cannot be directly retrieved using IMPORTXML. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this. I apologize for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importxml Imported Content Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217955/importxml-imported-content-empty)

Comment: I searched them all, I couldn't manage to find a way around that. But thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the Documentation text, I see.

As you have found out, you cannot simply `ImportXML()` for dynamic data in websites. Instead, what you need to do is look for how the data is getting retrieved. My first instinct is always to check the Network Monitor. I found that it was calling `https://alpha.kite.com/api/editor/symbol/python;pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.sum` via HTTP GET. The response is a JSON with our data whose path is `/report/description_text`.

This means we need a way to parse JSON data, which we can do with the Apps Script [`ImportJSON`](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs). Add that script to your sheet (Tools > Script Editor), then:

```
=ImportJSON("https://alpha.kite.com/api/editor/symbol/python;pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.sum","/report/description_text","noHeaders")
```

And that should give you the text you want.