# How to get the correct XPath for =ImportXML

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, soundcloud

```
=importXML("https://soundcloud.com/michael-barrera-24/tracks","//*[@class='infoStats__value sc-font-tabular-light']")
```

This is what I am using in the cell now. The website link is here: https://soundcloud.com/michael-barrera-24

I am trying to return how many follows I have. I am trying to stay updated with google sheets. It should return 13. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to some of the other answers - one of the bigger reasons it doesnt work is because of the URL, your missing the protocol:

`http://`  - google sheets wont process your importxml without it being an absolute URL and the best xpath to get is this one:

`//meta[@property='soundcloud:follower_count']/@content`

```
=IMPORTXML("https://soundcloud.com/michael-barrera-24","//meta[@property='soundcloud:follower_count']/@content")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want `XPath` to return `13`, try

```
//div[@class="infoStats__value sc-font-tabular-light"]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

This page has three div elements matching your xpath expression. You can point to particular div element you want to retrieve like this:

```
//a[contains(@href, "followers")]/div/text()
```

or you can slightly adjust your xpath  just add parentheses and specify you want a first div:

```
(//*[@class='infoStats__value sc-font-tabular-light']/text())[1]
```

Comment: So I tried both ways and they looked like this:    

=importXML("https://soundcloud.com/michael-barrera-24","//a[contains(@href, 'followers')]/div/text()")

and 

=importXML("https://soundcloud.com/michael-barrera-24","(//*[@class='infoStats__value sc-font-tabular-light']/text())[1]")       

But I am getting a #N/A in google sheets. The imported content is empty.

Comment: Xpath expression is valid but the page contents you see in your browser is generated by javascript, and Google spreadsheet doesn't execute js. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766174/importxml-parse-error)